# What is the difference between MMX PANDN and BMI ANDN?

Tags: assembly, instructions, mmx, bmi

What is the difference between the MMX instruction `PANDN` and the BMI 1.0 instruction `ANDN` ?

Comment: `ANDN`  operates on general purpose registers, `PANDN` operates on vector registers.

Comment: The insn set reference should make it obvious.  See http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/, or links to the original PDFs in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).